# Why "Money" And "Float" are giving same result that is "1"?

Tags: g1ant

```
♥float = ⟦float⟧1.00000000000000000000000000006
♥money = ⟦money⟧1.00000000000000000000000000006
program notepad
dialog ♥float
dialog ♥money
```

I am getting text as "1" in dialoge box for both the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Range for `float` and `money` types are limited in the G1ANT language I believe. C# `float` itself has a limited range of 6 - 9 digits [(C# Documentation Here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). I changed the values to a shorter one and it works. Screenshots below:
[image: Floating point value Dialog Box]

[image: Money value dialog box]

Comment: Float structure in G1ANT is a C# double type so you can have 15 decimal places. Money structure is a C# decimal and you should have up to 29 decimal places but there is a bug which will be fixed soon.

Comment: Works fine in a latest G1ANT.Studio, except that Money (and backing it up decimal type) type holds up to 28 digits, not 29.